# Finding a MerchantAccount in Braintree (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, braintree

It's possible to find most Braintree records using this syntax:

```
Braintree::Customer.find(customer_id)
Braintree::Transaction.find(transaction_id)
```

However, when looking for a MerchantAccount, I get this error:

```
Braintree::MerchantAccount.find(merchant_id)
=> undefined method `find' for Braintree::MerchantAccount:Class
```

I'm assuming there is some sort of lookup that we can do. If so, what's the syntax?

UPDATE:

Here are the [docs](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/ruby).

Comment: what is the documentation link of this gem..please provide that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contacted Braintree, and as of September 2013, they do not support this functionality.